# Is there an expandable tab bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I received a requirement that it needs an expandable tab bar, like **ExpansionTile** in Flutter,  when there are over 5 tabs.
(5 tabs show in tab bar, and all tabs show in expanded list.)

I made a custom Class from **ExpansionTile** likes below and make work like what **TabBar** do, and other tabs were hided by using **Offstage**.

[image]

But, there is a question here.
Two of these tabs are hiding, but the space and controller still work with 7 tabs. When I choose Tab7, the animation of controller will go to the position where Tab7 must show.

[image]

I think maybe I can just use **ListView** to build a tab bar and make it works like origin **TabBar**, so as **TabBarView**.
But this way will heavily change the project files, so I consider that is there a proper(or easy) way to do it.

```
Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: tabBarWidth! ? null : 315.w,
            height: toolbarHeight,
            child: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
              appBar: AppBar(
                elevation: 0,
                toolbarHeight: toolbarHeight,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: TabBar(
                          labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          indicatorPadding: indicatorLengthNormal!
                              ? EdgeInsets.zero
                              : EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                          indicator: CustomUnderlineTabIndicator(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: widget.indicatorColor == null
                                  ? AppColor.main_color!
                                  : widget.indicatorColor!,
                              width: indicatorWeight!,
                            ),
                            lineStroke: strokeStyle!,
                          ),
                          labelColor: widget.labelColor == null
                              ? AppColor.main_color
                              : widget.labelColor,
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12.sp,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontFamily: 'MicrosoftYaHei',
                            color: widget.labelColor == null
                                ? AppColor.main_color
                                : widget.labelColor,
                          ),
                          unselectedLabelColor:
                              widget.unselectedLabelColor == null
                                  ? AppColor.main_text_color
                                  : widget.unselectedLabelColor,
                          unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12.sp,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontFamily: 'MicrosoftYaHei',
                            color: widget.unselectedLabelColor == null
                                ? AppColor.main_text_color
                                : widget.unselectedLabelColor,
                          ),
                          tabs: [
                            for (int i = 0; i < widget.tabBarList.length; i++)
                              widget.isNeedTranslate!
                                  ? Offstage(offstage:i > 4 && widget.isPromoPage!, child:Tab(text: Translations.of(context)!.text(widget.tabBarList[i])))
                                  : Offstage(offstage:i > 4 && widget.isPromoPage!, child:Tab(text: widget.tabBarList[i]))
                          ],
                          controller: widget.tabController,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: we can do it by fixing TabItemSize. can you add your code snippet?

Comment: Update code snippet